# jQuery mobile panel breaks css position:fixed in autodivider linkbar

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, panel, css-position

I'm trying to use a jQuery mobile panel on the same page with a jQuery mobile autodivider linkbar that has css position:fixed. (See fiddle link below.)

In Chrome (and iOS Safari), when the panel div ("#defPanel") is present, the linkbar div ("#sorter") loses its fixed positioning and scrolls with the page. In Firefox, the linkbar stays fixed to the right of the window as expected.

If I remove the JQM panel div:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="defPanel">...</div>
```

... the linkbar's position:fixed works as expected in Chrome. Can anybody tell what the problem is here?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FC6WG/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that adding a panel messes up `position:fixed` as well, due to JQM adding in a giant div wrapper (with class `.ui-panel-content-wrap`) around your page content with:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Overriding that with:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-transform: none;
```

allows the fixed content to work properly.  Not sure if that messes something else up inadvertently but that did the trick for me!

Comment: That did it. Just one thing: I had to increase the specificity of the css selector like this:
`div.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-wrap {...}`
Other ways of increasing specificity caused the panel links to break for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `position:fixed` doesn't work in mobile browsers*. JQM uses some more or less sane hacks to try and make elements fixed. A general rule - avoid fixing anything if you can if you want to go mobile. If you use JQM use `data-position="fixed"`.

See some articles on fixing (and avoiding it ;-)):

- http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/
- http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/docs/widgets/headers/bars-fixed.php

*) Well OK, it does sometimes... but not really :-).

Comment: The problem here is not simply that position:fixed isn't reliable. The javascript (see the fiddle link posted above) also updates the position of the #sorter div whenever the page scrolls. That is, it's supposed to. But it doesn't work in Chrome (desktop or mobile) when there is a JQM 1.3 panel present.